# react.js setState successfully but get the initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set the initial value of selectdate to {name:'123'}, then update it in another place and update it successfully, and in other places, the selectdata is correct,but in the click function, I get the initial value.

```
const [selectData, setSelectData] = useState({name:'123'})


const determineOrder = async (obj) => {
    let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    let list = orderList
    if (clone.itemId != undefined) {
        clone.index = list.length
        clone.quantity = 1
        clone.select = true
        clone['orderItemsOptions'] = []
        // clone['itemOptions'] = []
        setSelectData(clone)  // update successfully
        list.forEach(element => { element.select = false })
        list.push(clone)
        await setOrderList([...list])
        await setTimeout(() => {
            contentListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
        }, 200);
    } else {
        var key = null
        var select = selectData
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            const element = list[i];
            if (element.index === select.index) {
                key = i
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(key)
        console.log(select)  // log {name:'123'}
        ............
 }
```

when `clone.itemId != undefined` is `true`， `setSelectData(clone)` is successful, and click this is function, the print is correct.

```
const setPrice = () => {
   console.log(selectData)  // this is right
}
```

But `clone.itemId != undefined` is `false`, the value of `selectdata` is `{name:'123'}`, and I'm sure I did it first `clone.itemId ! = undefined` is `true`

Comment: I don't think we can help without a complete example. Accessing `stale` values is always an issue with not updating/rebinding the corresponding function.

Comment: Thats how it works, `determineOrder ` only have the initial value. When selectData change this function will not be aware of it as its already initialized.  You have 2 options 1) When you call `determineOrder ` you can pass `selectData` as 2nd parameter eg: `determineOrder(obj, selectData)` or you can use `useCallback` hook and added `selectData` in dependency array.

Comment: The `determineorder`  is passed to the child component as props